# Bicubic Interpolation in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am writing a pretty standard program for bicubic interpolation. For some reason, if I make my Xincrement and Yincrement too small, the for loop starts exiting one time too soon. Not sure why this is happening.
I set my Yincrement and Xincrement in the main and if they are .25 or higher, then it works fine, but if i decrease it to .2 or lower, it stops one loop early.
Also, the last 3 for-loops are the ones that are messing up.

Here's my code:

```
public static double ApplyKernel(double [] Row, double Location, int R) {
  double s1; double s2; double s3; double s4;
  double Kernel;
  double s = Location%1;
  s1 = -.5*Math.pow(s+1,3)+2.5*Math.pow(s+1,2)-4*(s+1)+2;
  s2 = 1.5*Math.pow(s,3)-2.5*Math.pow(s,2)+1;
  s3 = 1.5*Math.pow(1-s,3)-2.5*Math.pow(1-s,2)+1;
  s4 = -.5*Math.pow(2-s,3)+2.5*Math.pow(2-s,2)-4*(2-s)+2;
  if(s==0) {
    Kernel = Row[(int)(Location)];
      } else {
    Kernel = s1*Row[(int)(Location-1)]+s2*Row[(int)Location]+s3*Row[(int)   (Location+1)]+s4*Row[(int)(Location+2)];
  }  
return Kernel;      
}

public static double[][] zValues(double [][] ExtendP,  int R, double X, double Y, double    Xincrement, double Yincrement) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  String phFileName = "Data37.txt";
  PrintStream phOutput = new PrintStream( phFileName );

  double[][] zValues = new double[(int)(R/Xincrement)+1][(int)(R/Yincrement)+1];
  double[] row = new double[R+3];
  for (double i = 1; i<=(R+1); i += Xincrement) {
    phOutput.println(";");
    for (int j = 0; j<R+3; j++) {
      row[j] = ApplyKernel(ExtendP[j], i, R);
    }
    for(double k = 1; k<=(R+1); k += Yincrement) {
        zValues[(int)((i-1)/Xincrement)][(int)((k-1)/Yincrement)] = ApplyKernel(row, k, R);
        phOutput.printf("(%.2f,%.2f) = %.3f ", k, i, ApplyKernel(row, k, R));  
      }
    }


  return zValues;
}
```

Let me know if you guys have any idea why this is happening

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 1):

Main advice: *do not iterate with a `double`*. By repeatedly adding to it you are accumulating error and in certain cases you suffer from fencepost issues.

Instead iterate with an `int` and use an appropriate formula to derive your double value in a single calculation step. This will simply involve an appropriate scaling of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are looping through code like this you really should be using `ints` to do the loops.  Ints are exact and won't be approximated.

Looping with Doubles will get you rounding errors or just imprecision due to the approximate nature of representing doubles. This error becomes greater as you keep modifying the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a floating point error. Since `R` is of type `int` and i,k are of type double, there maybe comparisons which are theoretically equal, but may not evaluate to be so due to floating point precision.